# Variable number of Oauth Authentication Schemes in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I'm building a .NET Core service that needs to register an OAuth authentication scheme for each entry in a database. I'm using Autofac in addition to .NET's DI.

The problem is that in order to know how to add the Oauth schemes I need to be able to go to the database. Here's what I tried -

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OAuth1";

        })
        .AddCookie();

        builder.Populate(services);
        var container = builder.Build();

        CreateAuths(authBuilder, container).Wait();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }

private async Task CreateAuths(AuthenticationBuilder authBuilder, IContainer container)
    {
        var dbService = container.Resolve<IDatabaseService>();
        var things = await dbService.GetAllThings().ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var thing in things)
        {
            authBuilder.AddOAuth(thing.Name, CreateOAuthOptionsForThing(thing));
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that I'm creating the Oauths to the AuthenticationBuilder AFTER I've called builder.Populate(services); so Autofac doesn't put the OAuths into the object graph.

Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: You can resolve the IAuthenticationSchemeProvider (?) and add your schemes directly to that.

Comment: @Tratcher - can you provide any more detail? I'm struggling a bit. I seem to be able to add an auth scheme but I'm not sure how to hook up my OAuthOptions to that scheme. Here's another SO question which seems to be asking the same thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910070/adding-new-authentication-schemes-dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example of how to do this here - https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/DynamicSchemes

Keep in mind that for OAuth schemes, you'll have to do more then just calling schemeProvider.AddScheme and optionsCache.TryAdd - there's also a "postconfigure" step when adding options via the normal method. Here's the class - https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthPostConfigureOptions.cs

So you can register the type "OAuthPostConfigureOptions<OAuthOptions, OAuthHandler<OAuthOptions>>" into your DI container then grab it via a constructor and call OAuthPostConfigureOptions.PostConfigure on your options before adding the options to the optionsCache.