# How to add runtime openId configuration in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

After a research, I got t know we can use SchemeProvider to use AddScheme at runtime from below links

[Adding new authentication schemes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910070/adding-new-authentication-schemes-dynamically)

https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/DynamicSchemes

My concern is how to add OpenIdConnectOptions at run time where all values of OpenIdConnectOptions will come from database in .net core